# Finding the CDF using the definition of CDF.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure how to proceed from here using strictly the definition of the CDF:

> Let a point be selected from the sample space $\mathcal{C} = \{c : 0 < c < 10\}$. Let $C \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ and let the probability set function be $P(C) = \int_C 1/10 dx$ Define the random variable $X$ to be $X(c) = c^2$. Find the CDF and the PDF of $X$.

The CDF is defined by $F_X(x) = P_X((-\infty, x]) = P(X \leq x) = P(\{c \in \mathcal{C} : x(c) \leq x\}) = P(\{c \in \mathcal{C} : c^2 \leq x\})$.

It is unclear where to go from here using just this definition. I could say:

$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_x(t)dt = \int_0^{x}(1/10)dt = (1/10)x$ for $x \in (0, 10)$,

but I'm not sure how to tie this back into $c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your start is correct with $F_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left(\left\{ c\in\left(0,10\right)\mid c^{2}\leq x\right\} \right)$.

Now discern the following cases:

- $x\geq100\qquad$ $F_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left(\left(0,10\right)\right)=1$.
- $0<x<100\quad$ $F_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left(\left(0,\sqrt{x}\right]\right)=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{10}\operatorname{d}c=\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{x}$.
- $x\leq0\qquad$ $F_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left(\emptyset\right)=0$ if $x\leq0$.

The PDF easily can be found as the derivative of $F_X$ in each case.